# Как превратить apk файл в папку?

Tags: android-studio, apk

**Дано**:

Андроид Студио, АПК.

**TODO**:

Превратить апк файл в папку.

Comment: Android Studio - IDE, среда для разработки приложений, а не их реверсинженеринга и взлома. Вам нужен apktool или многочисленные утилиты на его основе

Comment: `unzip your_app.apk` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor почти все файлы (кроме граф. ресурсов) в бинарном формате и простая распаковка не принесет никакого результата, все будет нечитаемо. кроме того, даже после правильной распаковки через apktool весь код будет в smali, а не java. читемыми будут только xml-файлы и потребуется еще одно преобразование smali - > java, но и после этого код будет далек от "человеческого", а вы unzip и готово...

Comment: @pavlofff `Превратить апк файл в папку.` ясное дело, что то что будет на выходе ­— это xml и бинарики. Но папка будет ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=decompile+apk&oq=decompile+apk&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3304j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно его открыть через apktool.